# Why is this .org file not using any org-mode highlighting?

Tags: org-mode, org-emphasis

I'm trying to highlight a syllable **within a word** in order to show that it is different from another word. How can I do this with <kbd>*</kbd> in org-mode and then properly export to LaTeX?

I'm on Windows 7 32-bit, Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32), Org-mode version 8.2.10.
I have followed the instructions [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218238/how-to-make-part-of-a-word-bold-in-org-mode) but something went wrong with Org -- it thinks an *.org file is a LaTeX file! I therefore had to comment out those lines in my *.emacs* configuration file. The lines I'm talking about are these:

```
(setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components " \t('\"{[:alpha:]")
(setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "[:alpha:]- \t.,:!?;'\")}\\")
(org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-regexp-components org-emphasis-regexp-components)
```

I don't know why, but they don't work with my emacs. Are they still valid? Can anyone help me out, please?
By the way I have this same question open on StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499238/org-file-not-recognized-after-character-emphasis-changes-in-the-emacs-file-wh))

## Screenshots

This is the structure of *vocab.org*. It has LaTeX tags at the bottom of the file so that when I export only the body as *vocab.tex*, it doesn't have problems recognizing *vocab-main.tex* as its master file. *vocab-main.tex* is a file containing all the font and page formatting that make the final pdf look good to the eyes.

[image: vocab.org file structure]

Comment: Can you switch to org-mode? (`M-x org-mode`)

Comment: Yes that works...temporarily only! At every restart of emacs, the problem reappears --  the text is white (I have opted for a dark emacs color-theme), as if it's plain text, no special Org-mode hooks applied to it. How do I fix it for good?

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong here but another solution is to use a zero width space character as described [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/mark-up-only-part-of-a-word/18511#18511)

Comment: From this discussion, it sounds like what you really want to do is have `*.org` files open in `org-mode` by default, is this correct? If so, you can add `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))` to your init file

Comment: @elethan I don't have a proper configuration for Org-mode since I usually work with AUCTEX but please have a look at my _.emacs_ file (see above). I placed the new lines right at the bottom. Is it correct? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @WobblyWindows, you shouldn't need any further configuration aside from `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))` to get `*.org` files to open in `org-mode`. Basically, you will get the effects of `M-x org-mode` in org files, without having to explicitly switch to `org-mode` This is what you want to do, right? Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I want any *.org file to be automatically recognized and I want the corresponding hooks and styles be applied to the file. However, I've tried shutting and restarting Emacs after updating and saving the _.emacs_ file as you said -- it's still giving trouble, **that** particular org file appears as plain text, instead of Org-mode file so each time I must type `M-x org-mode`

Comment: Call the help on the variable `magic-mode-alist` and report its value in your post. You get the help on variables with the key-combination `C-h v`. Note, that positive matches of the regular expressions and predicates in `magic-mode-alist` override `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: Since the entry `("\\.org\\'" . org-mode)` is already in my `auto-mode-alist` when I start emacs with the option `-Q` I do **not** think that you need the setting `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))` in your init file. Just try it for yourself. Start emacs with `-Q` and check wether you find the `org` extension in `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: @Tobias Help on `magic-mode-list` returns: "magic-mode-alist is a variable defined in `files.el'.
Its value is nil

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The figure you added in the question explains everything!
You have the line

`mode: latex`

in your file-local variables of the file `vocab.org`.
And `latex-mode` is exactly what you get!

If you need these lines in your org-file you should add a line with only the special form-feed character `^L` in it right after `#+END_LATEX`.
You can input the form-feed character by typing <kbd>C-q C-L</kbd> or <kbd>C-q C-l</kbd> (after <kbd>C-q</kbd> uppercase or lowercase letter L with control key pressed).

File local variables are searched from the end of the file. The form-feed character limits this search forcefully.

The end of your file should look like in the following picture.
Note the `^L` in the picture! It should be marked by some color as control character.

[image]

Comment: Wait a minute, I lost you there. How should it look then? `#+BEGIN_LaTeX: %%% Local Variables:  %%% mode: latex %%% TeX-master: "vocab-main" %%% End:  #+END_LaTeX  ^L` Is it correct? Is `^L` on the following new line? 'Cause it still doesn't see it as an org file and I have to type `M-x org-mode`...

Comment: Yes, the character sequence is `(insert "\n\014\n")` in lisp.

Comment: Just saw your edit. Re-wrote those tags, now things seems fine.